# Rails and Active Record: is possible to mass assign ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm migrating a Bulletin Board from PHP (mysql) to Rails (PG) and for SEO I must keep the same IDs for topics.

My migration script use the standard class methods, so I create a new topic with mass assignment. Using this solution postgres give me an incremental ID for my topic that is different from my original ID.

Is there any way to force the ID? I know that id are unique (they come from my mysql db) but I need to keep identity for SEO and for url rewrite. I found a solution searching here but now is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Create your migration like this:

```
create_table :table_name, {id: false} do |t|
  t.int :your_custom_id
  # .. other columns ...
end
execute "ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD PRIMARY KEY (your_custom_id);"
```

Finally, to let Rails view this non-standard `id` field as your primary ID, add the following code in your model:

```
set_primary_key :your_custom_id       # for Rails 3
self.primary_key = :your_custom_id    # for Rails 4
```

Now, set this field to be free from mass-protection, and use it like a normal field.

---

However, I will really advise you to simply setup a new table column (i.e. field), something like `old_id` and not to mess with default Rails `id` field. Once you do that, use that field in your routes.

Comment: I'm migrating to Discourse... maybe is better to keep the hands away from the source code. Any solution that doesn't require code changes in the destination platform?